# A simpler CORBA protocol? does it exist?

Tags: c++, sockets, corba

I want to be able to use one of CORBA functionalities, that is I want my CORBA client to execute a function on a CORBA server, pass arguments to the function and receive the return value of the function.
BUT, I would like to use a different protocol, a simpler one...Does such thing exist?

while going through the documentations and tutorials, I felt that CORBA is heavy and difficult to implement and manage.

so do the above functionality exist in another protocol?

EDIT: To clarify my question based on current answers,
I still didn't implement neither the server nor the client yet. My client needs to be able to execute functions on the server and pass arguments and receive return values. I am just wondering what other protocol can do that? in a simpler fashion?
Thanks.

Comment: There is lots of stuff similar but simpler than CORBA, but if you need to talk to a CORBA server, you'll have to use a protocol it supports. Or are you flexible on the server-side, too?

Comment: Yes, I am implementing client and server side, Server will be written in C++ (under Linux environment and qtCreator IDE) and client I didn't write it yet.

Comment: In most cases people are having a hard time learning the IDL to C++ binding. If you want to implement your client much more easily, check the IDL to C++11 mapping, that is much easier to use. See for example http://www.orbzone.org for details about this mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A CORBA client talking to a CORBA service - how do you expect them to speak anything else?

What CORBA functionality do you want to use?

Do you already have this client and server, or are you just thinking about how to implement them?

I don't see why implementation is that difficult, once you have IDL.  You'll use tools to help with the rest.  And management will be difficult regardless of protocol.  What are you imagining will be simpler?

I would consider ditching CORBA for an HTTP-based protocol.  CORBA has virtually disappeared for a reason - simple and open win.  HTTP based services can be implemented in the language of your choice - Java, C#, or something else - and can communicate with any client that can make an HTTP connection.  That's worth something if you're still in the design phase.

Comment: Well said. HTTP + a well-understood payload format (JSON, XML, whatever) + a scalable server implementation == success.

Comment: Hi there, yes I still didn't implement anything, i need to implement a server side and a client side. The corba funtionality I discussed is that the client needs to be able to execute funtions on the server and pass arguments and receive return values. I am just wondering what other protocol can do that? in a simpler fashion?

Comment: Like I said: HTTP is the way to go.  Google "web services" - you won't be able to absorb all that you'll get back.  I don't know what your criterion for "simpler" is.  It sounds to me like you want instant soup.  There's no magic in the world.  You'll have to do something, and changing protocols won't fix all the problems with CORBA.

Comment: Before I dig into this, you seem like a knowledgeable person :) so please bare with me here. From my understanding, if you want to use a web service, I will need a web server running on my server side that will handle the http requests from the client, am I correct? is that fast? i.e. would the client request be handle almost within less than a second and the result returned back?

Comment: I am also thinking to develop a TCP socket application between server and client, but I am trying to avoid this option since I will need to write some protocol defintions and so that the server and client can communicate robustly and understand each other. As you can tell I am a newbi here, so what do you think?

Comment: Bad idea.  Sockets are too low level.  Please do yourself a favor and read up on services as soon as you can.  You do need an app server, but you need to have the server running somehow.  It'll be fast enough, and the server will help you with management and such.  You don't want to have to duplicate all that for your raw socket.  If you're really concerned about performance, look into Netty: http://www.jboss.org/netty.  Noobs shouldn't think that they can improve on what's already been done by experts.

Comment: Exactly, it just that every time I google what I want to do I get sent to "WRITE A TCP SOCKET APPLICATION!" but I know that this has been done before, it must! that's why Im asking the question :). I will definetly look into that. Thank you for your help

Answer (score -1):

This topic is old, but I'll try to give my two cents.

CORBA is a standard middleware architecture for development of distributed object computing middleware. Therefore, objects are primitives of the system. In a high-level view, a client calls a method on an object that is located on another computer, a server, and gets the result as if the object was located on the client itself. In another words, it is a way to do RPC.

On a low-level standpoint, when a method is called on the client, it puts all parameters on a message, along with many other fields that will be used to identify the object on the server. This message is sent to the server, which reads the message and calls a method on the specified object. The method result is put on a message that is sent back to the client.

What can be done using CORBA's GIOP protocol (the message format), can also be done using a RESTful approach using the HTTP protocol. Similarly, you can create a client that puts all method arguments on a HTTP POST message (or GET message, depending on what you intend to do), sends that message to a HTTP server, which delivers the the message to a service, that evaluates your request and returns a response that is encapsulated on a HTTP response and then sent back to the client.

Although there is conceptual differences between distributed objects and RESTful services, both do the same thing: client-server communication. The difference between the two lies in HOW the communication is done. CORBA works with an IDL (short for Interface Description Language). This IDL describes the object interface, that includes all available methods, the types of the data passed as an argument or returned as response and other stuff. This IDL is then used to generate Stubs that can be compiled alongside your code. These stubs handle all nasty message serialization and communication code.

RESTful services, however, doesn't use IDL. Because the HTTP is a simple protocol, there is a plethora of open source http client libraries that can be used to encapsulate message parameters and call RESTful services, for many different languages (Java, C++, C#, Python, Ruby, Lua, Erlang, Haskell, Scheme, ...)

The disadvantage of IDL-based approaches is that you must regenerate the Stub for all clients every single time an object interface changes, which may be a source of a headache if you do this too much. The advantage claimed by this approach is that you can have compiler-based static checking for the message.

About the alternatives, there are many other RPC-style communication protocols these days. SOAP is a very famous alternative, and many prefer using it in contrast to CORBA. Other open source RPC protocols include Google's Protocol Buffers, Apache Thrift, Apache Avro and Message Pack.

Well, you should study a lot about RPC and distributed systems to gain more insight in these topics. I hope I was able to shed some light.